# Creating a table in AWS Managed Cassandra Services through Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to create a table in AWS Managed Cassandra Services through Cloud Formation?

I haven't found anything related to deployment of AWS Managed Cassandra Services through Cloud Formation in the official documentation.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_Cassandra.html

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-managed-apache-cassandra-service-mcs/), the service was launched in December 2019, so I can understand why support hasn't been added yet.

You could submit an issue to the [AWS CloudFormation roadmap](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap) so that they add coverage for it.